Does the YouTube spam filter flag repeated comments on various videos as spam, and if so, is there a comment threshold before detection?
I am building an app that would authenticate users using YouTube Data API V3 and allow my app to post comments on YouTube videos on behalf of the authenticated user. I've tried to find out best practices but could not find anything on how many same comments can be posted across different videos and in what duration keeping in mind avoiding spamming situations from the YouTube platform. Any guidance or information on the same will be helpful.
